# TravisCI not running my tests properly sometimes

Tags: rspec, continuous-integration, sinatra, cucumber, travis-ci

Every once and a while I've been getting this in travis on my opensource project(feel free to contribute if you want :D):

```
$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
1 gem installed
install
$ bundle install --deployment
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing rake (10.0.3) 
Installing backports (2.8.2) 
Installing builder (3.1.4) 
Installing mime-types (1.20.1) 
Installing nokogiri (1.5.6) 
Installing rack (1.5.1) 
Installing rack-test (0.6.2) 
Installing ffi (1.3.1) 
Installing childprocess (0.3.7) 
Installing multi_json (1.5.0) 
Installing rubyzip (0.9.9) 
Installing websocket (1.0.7) 
Installing selenium-webdriver (2.29.0) 
Installing xpath (1.0.0) 
Installing capybara (2.0.2) 
Installing coderay (1.0.8) 
Installing diff-lcs (1.2.0) 
Installing json (1.7.6) 
Installing gherkin (2.11.6) 
Installing cucumber (1.2.1) 
Installing dalli (2.2.1) 
Installing eventmachine (1.0.0) 
Installing multipart-post (1.1.5) 
Installing faraday (0.8.4) 
Installing faye-websocket (0.4.7) 
Installing git (1.2.5) 
Installing http_parser.rb (0.5.3) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Installing rdoc (3.12) 
Installing jeweler (1.8.4) 
Installing metaclass (0.0.1) 
Installing method_source (0.8.1) 
Installing mocha (0.13.2) 
Installing poltergeist (1.1.2) 
Installing slop (3.3.3) 
Installing pry (0.9.10) 
Installing rack-protection (1.3.2) 
Installing rspec-core (2.13.1) 
Installing rspec-expectations (2.13.0) 
Installing rspec-mocks (2.13.0) 
Installing rspec (2.13.0) 
Installing tilt (1.3.3) 
Installing sinatra (1.3.4) 
Installing sinatra-contrib (1.3.2) 
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
Post-install message from rdoc:
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
before_script.1
$ export DISPLAY=:99.0
before_script.2
$ sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
Starting virtual X frame buffer: Xvfb.
$ bundle exec rake
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber features --format pretty
undefined method `helpers' for Sinatra:Module (NoMethodError)
```

The build with problem can also been seen here:
https://travis-ci.org/thiagofm/memcached-manager/jobs/10071127

The code of the project is on the github:
https://github.com/thiagofm/memcached-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of sinatra you are running does not support ruby 2.0.0 , try a newer version.

gem install sinatra --pre